# "Failed to connect to repository" Error while setting up Github Jenkins Plugin

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am getting an error when inputting my repo location into the "Source Code Management > Git > Repository URL" section of a new Job. I have searched all around and tried many different URLs with no success.

Error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h https://github.com/micdoodle8/Crossbow_Mod_2.git HEAD
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You might need to set the path to your git executable in **Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Git -> Git Installations -> Path to Git executable**.

For example, I was getting the same error in Windows.  I had installed git with chocolatey, and got the location via Powershell:

```
Get-Command git.exe | Select Definition
```

In Unix, you should be able to do:

```
which git
```

Comment: Happened to me after I lost my profile, git.exe must have been in PATH and the new profile did not have that value. Had to reconfigure some of my Jenkins plugins as a result.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this configuration can be found under Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration in some versions of Jenkins

Comment: Forgot to install git on my server. Kudos!

Answer (score 22):

on Jenkins ver. 2.7.4, the setting property of (Path to Git executable) is now in Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Git -> Git Installations -> Path to Git executable.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same thing while connection to git from jenkins. Here is few checklist you would like to watch on :-

Jenkins Configuration :-
1) Check whether git executable is appropriately specified
2) Provide SSH repository link git@blahblah
3) Under credentials >> Select Username and Authentication key
(go to your server, Generate SSH keys ssh-keygen... Copy keys to JENKINS_HOME/,ssh)
You should be able to connect to your GIT repository from Jenkins

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't copied my key to JENKINS_HOME/.ssh which is why it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to set the path to your git executable in Manage Jenkins -> global tool configuration -> Git -> Git Installations -> Path to Git executable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may occur when your system can not locate git installation.
If you are using Jenkins on VM or local system, locate the git installation folder.
For me (CentOS machine on AWS) it was in

`/usr/bin/git`

Put this path in Jenkins in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Git -> Git Installations -> Path to Git executable`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should install the [Github Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) for Jenkins.

After installation, in "Configure" within the project, there should be an input field for "GitHub project". Input "https://github.com/micdoodle8/Crossbow_Mod_2" (without the quotes) there. Additionally you put the same in the input field which says "Repositories" (the one you mentioned in your question) beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your **path** to your **Git executable** which is in **Global Tool Configuration** of **Manage Jenkins**.
We can find location of a path via window power-shell as:
    **Get-Command git.exe | Select Definition**
shown in pcture as:
[command for git executable path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ1qK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm....if you have jenkins running in a VM, make sure you install the package 'git-core' or 'git':

```
sudo yum install git
```

After all, we must have git installed in the machine where jenkins is running. Otherwise you won't be able to run git commands.

Comment: Thanks `sudo yum install git` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all git should be properly installed in your system.

Check if after installing git, path is given in system environment variables.
Add below paths in system variables "path" after installing git
C:\Apps\Git\bin
C:\Apps\Git\cmd

to test - run $ git -v in cmd prompt

Next, go to Manage Jenkins -> global tool configuration -> Git -> Git Installations -> Path to Git executable -> enter path like C:\Apps\Git\bin\git.exe (wherever your git is installed)

For detailed description on this issues and git setup in Jenkins, you can check this blog post - https://thewebspark.com/2020/07/24/git-and-github-setup-in-jenkins/

Answer (score 0):

As described above by others, make sure that your Path to Git executable is right. Be careful though how you find it: `git --exec-path` might give you a wrong path, e.g. mine is C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core. Now, there IS a git.exe living there but this path in Path to Git executable seemed to be wrong. What you need is (sticking to my example above) C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

For Window it worked when I gave the complete path under the Global Tool Configuration:

C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

Answer (score -1):

This error can be resolved, if we change the path of Git on Global Configuration Tools page.

Use Path- C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

For Detailed steps refer [Click here](https://youtu.be/TqUk1QJA9Vo)

Comment: Can you explain it here instead of redirecting users to an external site

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33690639)