# Using Git with Jenkins on Windows

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Git 2.8.1, Jenkins 1.642.4 and Windows Server 2012 R2 and trying to access a project hosted with Git through https using Git plugin 2.4.4.

After setting my repository URL Jenkins gives me the following error message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Could not init C:\Windows\TEMP\hudsonblablabla
```

I have found several sources stating that this is due to not pointing Jenkins to the correct git location, [like in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123879/jenkins-with-tomcat-failed-to-connect-to-repository-could-not-init/31905487#31905487) however setting the absolute path to the git location has not fixed this issue for me.

Some of the paths I have already tried without luck:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd
```

Am I using the wrong path or is the issue something else?

Comment: Could it be related to folder permissions? Maybe the jenkins-user doesn't have write-access to C:\Windows\TEMP\

Comment: @EmilKantis How could I check that? It's being run as a service as is recommended for windows so I don't know what the user is in that case. Also there doesn't seem to be any TEMP folder (only Temp) if that changes anything.

Comment: You can check folder permissions by right-clicking the folder in explorer, hit properties -> Security. http://imgur.com/a/GIo9q , You can also check which user the service is running as by hitting Start -> Run... -> type services.msc -> Right click jenkins service -> Properties -> Log on

Comment: The service is running under Local System and SYSTEM seems to have full rights to Temp so I guess that works out. Could it be tripping over the temp folder been named Temp not TEMP?

Comment: Windows' filesystem is case-insensitive, so that shouldn't be the case

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a incorrect repository url. For some reason it showed this error instead of the usual "not a git repository" error.